# OPEN FDA spam phone calls

Tags: openfda

I am receiving unwanted voice messages detailing several FDA initiatives from 909-394-5110.  It talks about inspections detecting illegal drugs and also a short blurb about Open FDA and natural gas extraction.

can you guide me to the responsible organization that is spamming me with FDA subject matter?

Very Respectfully,

Roy Malmberg

Comment: truly hate beating a dead horse here....but this is yet another problem with outsourcing their q&a. voting not to close as its somewhat openfda related

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear about this. Please email this note to openfda@fda.hhs.gov and it will be routed to the right place.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3698)

Comment: @Skram eh? The question was "can you guide me to..." and the answer was "here's who to contact". It seems to be exactly the answer desired.

Comment: Andrew - my comment is in line with @albert's comment above. This isn't really a question for Open Data SE and so its not really an answer either, IMHO

Comment: This isn't an openFDA system or an FDA system. However, given that the caller is referencing FDA, it will be researched by the right people internally at FDA and appropriate action will be taken. SE is not the right forum for this.

Comment: just to weigh in here...and i'm not sure about which is right...if this is a place for all questions openfda, this question and answer are correct. i think. i do not think this should be a place for any org to direct all of their q&a, especially in an open data sense. part of open data (to me) is owning your data. these orgs should be much more proactive on their sites....i actually agree with Skram and Andrew here. sounds confusing? it is.